# AS3 String to XML

Tags: javascript, xml, string, actionscript-3

I have a JS code reading a div's content and returning string data.
Than I want to read this and convert to XML

First converting `<` to `&lt;` and `>` to `&gt;` than get string from html:

```
XmlData = String(ExternalInterface.call("ReadXmlContent"));
```

Create XML:

```
bookxml = new XML(XmlData);

aaaa.htmlText +="bookxml "+ bookxml.toXMLString() + " <br>" // shows complete xml

aaaa.htmlText +="length"+ bookxml.content.page.length() + " <br>"; // shows : 0
```

Complete xml is showing but can't read xml nodes.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Could you show the resulting XML Structure? I had the same problem once.

Comment: Very very thanks. You asked true question. My xml node like this : "<MediaObject Title='name' MediaObjectID='14' X1='42,00' Y1='3,00' X2='72,00' Y2='31,00' MediaType='video'/>" and browser is converts this "<mediaobject Title='name' MediaObjectID='14' X1='42,00' Y1='3,00' X2='72,00' Y2='31,00' MediaType='video'></mediaobject>" and also converts all node names to lowercase. if you answer the question i can accept yours. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. i explained the problem.

Comment: Why don't you give the solution as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for bad english.
Thanks @Anton for helpful question
Solution:

My Xml nodes:

```
<MediaObject Title='name' MediaObjectID='14' X1='42,00' Y1='3,00' X2='72,00' Y2='31,00' MediaType='video'/>
<MediaObject Title='name' MediaObjectID='15' X1='3,00' Y1='3,00' X2='34,00' Y2='31,00' MediaType='video'/>
```

if u use xml nodes inside a div the browser converts this:

```
<mediaobject title='name' mediaobjectid='14' x1='42,00' y1='3,00' x2='72,00' y2='31,00' mediatype='video'>
<mediaobject title='name' mediaobjectid='15' x1='3,00' y1='3,00' x2='34,00' y2='31,00' mediatype='video'></mediaobject></mediaobject>
```

Browser changing nodes and also converts node names and attributes to lowercase.

Solutions:
use xml as value like below and read it. So browser not add nodes and not change node names/attributes to lowercase. Don't forget to use attributes values with "'":

```
<input type="hidden" name="xmldata" id="xmldata" value="<Contents><Content PreviousContentID='30' PreviousContentName='aaa' NextContentID='28' NextContentName='aaa'><Page Number='3' RelativePath='images/res1.jpg' AbsolutePath='a.net'><MediaObject Title='aaa' MediaObjectID='58' X1='38,64' Y1='50,37' X2='54,06' Y2='54,25' MediaType='link'></MediaObject><MediaObject Title='aaa' MediaObjectID='58' X1='8,43' Y1='2,27' X2='33,12' Y2='24,31' MediaType='link'></MediaObject></Page></Content></Contents>">
```

if u want to use inside a div:
use node names and attributes as lowercase,
don't use lines like this:

```
<mediaobject title='name' mediaobjectid='14' x1='42,00' y1='3,00' x2='72,00' y2='31,00' mediatype='video'/>
```

change it to this:

```
<mediaobject title='name' mediaobjectid='14' x1='42,00' y1='3,00' x2='72,00' y2='31,00' mediatype='video'></mediaobject>
```